# Simple Express app 'Cannot GET /'

Tags: node.js, express

I am running: node v6.2.2, npm v3.9.5, express v4.13.4

I have run the following from the book 'CORS in Action' - Monsur Hossain.

$ node app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var POSTS = {
'1': {'post': 'This is the first blog post.'},
'2': {'post': 'This is the second blog post.'},
'3': {'post': 'This is the third blog post.'}
};
var SERVER_PORT = 9999;
var serverapp = express();
serverapp.use(express.static(__dirname));
serverapp.get('/api/posts', function(req, res) {
res.json(POSTS);
});
serverapp.listen(SERVER_PORT, function() {
console.log('Started server at http://127.0.0.1:' + SERVER_PORT);
});
```

In the browser at localhost:9999   I get,

```
Cannot GET /
```

The directory looks like this,

[image]

EDIT:

In /api/posts I have

```
var POSTS = {
'1': {'post': 'This is the first blog post.'},
'2': {'post': 'This is the second blog post.'},
'3': {'post': 'This is the third blog post.'}
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you have defined a route for `'/api/posts'`, you need to define a route for `'/'`.

Example:

```
serverapp.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})
```

Comment: I thought the idea was to get the json from /api/posts which is where I have var POSTS = {
'1': {'post': 'This is the first blog post.'},
'2': {'post': 'This is the second blog post.'},
'3': {'post': 'This is the third blog post.'}
};

Comment: In order to get the response from /api/posts, you need to navigate to http://localhost:9999/api/posts. The reason why you were getting an error was because you were hitting http://localhost:9999/, and there was not a route for '/'. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you haven't actually defined a route for your `/` page.

To do this you could change `/api/posts` to just `/` in your example.